# How do I pass an id from an attributes table into a link_to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, activeadmin

I'm trying to do something like this in my venues.rb file for active admin:

```
show do |f|
    attributes_table do
      row :id
      row :name
      row :modification_comments do
        link_to "modification history", admin_venue_modification_comments_path(:id)
      end
    end
end
```

Where the id attribute is on a model venue that has many modification comments. But the path being generated looks like this "admin/venues/id/modification_comments" (note that instead of the actual id the symbol is converted into a string)

My rake routes looks like this:

```
batch_action_admin_venue_modification_comments POST       /admin/venues/:venue_id/modification_comments/batch_action(.:format) admin/modification_comments#batch_action
             admin_venue_modification_comments GET        /admin/venues/:venue_id/modification_comments(.:format)              admin/modification_comments#index
                                               POST       /admin/venues/:venue_id/modification_comments(.:format)              admin/modification_comments#create
          new_admin_venue_modification_comment GET        /admin/venues/:venue_id/modification_comments/new(.:format)          admin/modification_comments#new
         edit_admin_venue_modification_comment GET        /admin/venues/:venue_id/modification_comments/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/modification_comments#edit
              admin_venue_modification_comment GET        /admin/venues/:venue_id/modification_comments/:id(.:format)          admin/modification_comments#show
                                               PUT        /admin/venues/:venue_id/modification_comments/:id(.:format)          admin/modification_comments#update
                                               DELETE     /admin/venues/:venue_id/modification_comments/:id(.:format)          admin/modification_comments#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a symbol use object f:

```
link_to "modification history", admin_venue_modification_comments_path(f.id)
```